# Learning Cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-python

I want to learn cocos2d on UBUNTU 11.06
I have found tutorials, But if you people can help, then I can learn efficiently.

If you know any Link / Tutorial / book, please let me know

Answer (score 1):

I have gathered some knowledge from http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/ ,but not exact for UBUNTU..

Answer (score 1):

You can go to [Cocos2D Python's programming guide](http://python.cocos2d.org/doc/programming_guide/index.html), and I also recommend using other guides online such as the [one I've put on GitHub](https://github.com/LiamRahav/cocos2d-python-tutorials).

Comment: While link only answers are typically frowned upon, its exactly what the poster requested, so I just say Welcome to Stack Overflow!